# Using a async function in createConnection of promise-mysql does change anything at loading speed?

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, express, ecmascript-6

I need to know if it is better to use asynchronous createConnection or not

Does this change anything at loading speed?

I'm using express, ReactJS, promise-mysql

**What should I use?**

**This:**

```
    async connect ()  {
            try{
                const conn = await db.createConnection(this.config);
                this.conn = conn;
            } catch(error){
                console.log(error)
            }   
        }
```

**Or this**

```
      connect ()  {
            return db.createConnection(this.config).then(conn => {
                this.conn = conn
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error handling is completely different in your two examples.  In the first, you log the error and allow the returned promise to then be resolved.  In the second, a connection error will reject the returned promise.  So, that's a major structural difference.

If you changed the first one to this:

```
async connect ()  {
    this.conn = await db.createConnection(this.config);
}
```

Then, that would be structurally the same as your second example:

```
connect ()  {
    return db.createConnection(this.config).then(conn => {
        this.conn = conn;
    });
}
```

Now, if you compare these two they have the same outcomes (except in an edge case where `db.createConnection()` would throw synchronously which it hopefully doesn't do).

So, then if you reasked your question based on these two that have the same outcomes, the answer is that it doesn't really make a difference.

If there was a measurable difference in execution speed, it would be so small as to be very unlikely to be meaningful and whatever difference there was would be only dependent upon the particular JS engine implementation and likely not constant as the JS engine matures.

So, it's really just a matter of coding style and which you prefer.  The `await` version is less typing, less lines of code (as it often is).  I personally tend to not use `async/await` unless I have more than one asynchronous operation that I'm trying to sequence, but that's perhaps just some inertia from coding with `.then()` for awhile before `await` came along.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you for sharing your knowledge! :)